# How to push Apache Airflow containers to Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker-compose, airflow, azure-container-registry

I followed the tutorial to get Airflow running locally using Docker Compose [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html) but now I want to get it running in **Azure using containers**.

There's no tutorials for this in the Airflow documentation, and the only thing I've found related to Azure is about deploying multi-container apps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose), so I'm wondering what needs to be done (i.e., modifications to the compose .yaml file).

My thinking was to use `docker-compose up` and then somehow push it to the **Azure Container Registry**, but obviously a lot is missing in between...

Does anyone have experience with this that they could share?

Comment: please post the error you are getting.

Comment: Docker Compose is not intended to push the images to the registry but to run an application that consists of multiple images. You need to push each individual image listed in the docker-compose.yaml to the registry first and then modify the yaml to use the images from that registry instead from the default DockerHub location. If you want to just run Airflow in Azure, you don't need to push the images to ACR though. You can use the same Compose file to run it in a VM that you spin up in Azure that has Docker and Docker Compose installed. Hope this helps.